# Draw d3 Axis with React/Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I'm trying to render an Axis with React, d3 and Typescript. I will show the code and the staten the problem.

```
class Axis extends React.Component<{}> {
  private ref: React.RefObject<SVGGElement>;

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.ref = React.createRef();
  }

  public componentDidMount() { 
    this.renderAxis();
  }

  public componentDidUpdate() {
    this.renderAxis();
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <g transform="translate(10,30)" ref={this.ref} />
    )
  }


  private renderAxis = () => {
    const scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 10]).range([0, 200]);

    const axis = d3.axisBottom(scale);
    d3**.select(this.ref)**.call(axis);
  }
}

export default Axis;
```

I create a SVG **g** element which should hold the axis. I therefore create a ref to be able to access this element later.

```
private ref: React.RefObject<SVGGElement>;
<g transform="translate(10,30)" ref={this.ref} />
```

When I try to select this element here...

```
d3.select(this.ref).call(axis);
```

...I get the error on *this.ref*: Argument of type 'RefObject' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BaseType'

I can't figure out what I am supposed to do here. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

**SOLVED**

Okay I feel stupid right now. I accessed the ref wrongly..
It was supposed to be *this.ref* **.current**